# PHP Variable into Html Label/text

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a program that saves data that I fill in the textboxes on the first page. But on the secondpage I have a search button that, if I fill in an ID or name, that it will receive all the extra data from the name and Id. I want to put this data in a label(html) on a second page.

```
$query="SELECT * from customers WHERE id = '$id'";
```

Now I want to put the data in a variable and then put this variable in my html in a textbox or label with using Id/name/value or something.

Is that possible?

Comment: Please add your example codes tou your question !

Comment: There are hundreds of tutorials that show how to put the display the results of a query on a web page. SO is not a substitute for learning the basics first.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you understand the concept by looking at the code below. You may want to prevent against sql injection and use prepared statement too

```
$sql = "select * from customers where id = '$id'";
   $result = mysql_query($conn, $sql);

if($result){
          $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

          if($count > 0){

           while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

              $firstName = $row['firstname'];

              echo'
                     <input type="text" value="$firstname">
                   ';

             }

          }
}
```